# Required roles to enable a device to use ActiveSync on MS365

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id

The tenant I administer has administrative users that aren´t Global Administrators but have a number of roles, including Exchange Administrator, but can´t enable a device to use ActiveSync (the page sent in the quarantine email does not open, the Enable button is greyed in Mobile Device Details pop-up in Mailbox features/Mobile devices/View details).

These users cannot open the old EAC as well, that have the Mobile session.

Does anybody know what other permissions should I grant?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD admin roles is one thing, but Exchange Online has additional (internal, specific) Role Based Access Control.

You need to make sure your admin account has the 'Mail Recipients' Admin Role in Exchange Online.

It is contained in either Organization Management' or 'Recipient Management' role groups.

[Here is how to assign it.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/permissions-exo/role-groups)

How to check required permissions for a cmdlet in Exchange Online Powershell:

```
Get-ManagementRole -Cmdlet Set-CASMailbox -CmdletParameters ActiveSyncEnabled
```

Comment: Right: 'Recipient Management' role in Exchange Online did the trick!

Many thanks.

And many thanks also for the Powershell command, it will be very very useful in other situations.

Happy new year!